# How to fix image updated problem in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image

I wrote a function to update background image:

```
function selectBackground(backgroundId) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/BackgroundImages/" + backgroundId,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    let backgroundData = data.backgroundImageData;
                    let covertedImgData = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + backgroundData;
                    document.getElementById("backgroundImage").src = covertedImgData;
                    let currentBgImage = document.getElementById("backgroundImage");
                    layout.setBackgroundImage(currentBgImage);
                },
                failure: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

The image data in the database has type Byte[], so I add a string in front of the image data:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64
```

When I run it, the browser doesn't update the background image automatically.

[image]

I have to use "ctrl + F5" to see the updated background image in the browser.

[image]

How can I fix the code to make the background image shown correctly when calling the function?

Thank you!

Update:

I solved the issue by update

```
setBackground(currentBgImage);
```

to

```
setTimeout(() => {
    setBackground(currentBgImage);
}, 1);
```

Comment: Yurgh, `async: false`... What is `layout.setBackgroundImage` ?

Comment: @JeremyThille It's a function to set the background image in a div.

Comment: But you already set the image source with `getElementById("backgroundImage").src = covertedImgData`. So what does `layout.setBackgroundImage` do on top of that?

Comment: @JeremyThille   the img with id "backgroundImage" is set to hidden.  I use layout.setBackground to show the image in the div.

Comment: Oh, I see. But what is the code? Maybe the error is in there. Like, the image is set, but then `layout.setBackgroundImage` fails to reveal it